# What is the Xcode equivalent for Visual Studio's C++ char(248), the degree symbol?

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm using using Xcode on a Mac.

I'm trying to print the degree symbol in the console in Xcode using `cout << char(248);`.

I tried this:

```
cout << "F" << char(248) << '\t' << "C" << char(248) << endl;
```

The output is showing: F\370    C\370 (I was expecting degree symbol after F and C)

I tried the same thing on my PC's Visual Studio and it worked. So I'm guessing it's not the same command for Xcode. How do I display this in Xcode?

Comment: Terminal on macOS expect Utf-8 encoding. Look for Utf-8 code of ° and use it, or copy it from my comment and use it in your code.

Comment: `char(248)` depends on the regional settings on Windows. It's not a common Windows-specific thing.

Comment: Assuming UTF-8 then `cout << char(194) << char(176)`. Now would be a good time to learn about Unicode and [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

Comment: OEM 437: `cout << "\xF8\n";`.  Macintosh Terminal UTF-8: `cout << "\xC2\xB0\n";`.